# WinAPI text output in C

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, text

I'm fairly new to WINAPI, and I need some help doing text output. I have an array of pixels that I write to with functions and then periodically blit onto the screen using the following functions:

```
DWORD WINAPI tickThreadProc(HANDLE handle) {
ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOW );
HDC hdc = GetDC( hwnd );
hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( hdcMem, hbmp );
int delay = 1000 / fps;
InitPhys();
LoadIMGs();
for ( ;; ) {
    onFrame( pixels );

    BitBlt( hdc, gLeft, gTop, width, height, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );
    // Wait
    Sleep( delay );
    // Physics
    SimPhys();  
}
SelectObject( hdcMem, hbmOld );
DeleteDC( hdc );
return 0;
}


void MakeSurface(HWND hwnd) {
BITMAPINFO bmi;
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight =  -height; // Order pixels from top to bottom
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; // last byte not used, 32 bit for alignment
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bmi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbGreen = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbRed = 0;
bmi.bmiColors[0].rgbReserved = 0;
HDC hdc = GetDC( hwnd );
// Create DIB section to always give direct access to pixels
hbmp = CreateDIBSection( hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&pixels, NULL, 0 );
DeleteDC( hdc );
// Create a new thread to use as a timer
hTickThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, &tickThreadProc, NULL,0, NULL );
}
```

This is modified off some code I found on the internet. The pixel struct has 4 ints for r, g, b, and a.

I need to do text output and loading a picture for text is impractical. Any help?

Comment: Like the [`TextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: Yes, sort of. But I can't use the PAINSTRUCT stuff.

Comment: +1 for 'PAINSTRUCT' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use GetDC to get a handle to device context, you must use ReleaseDC when you're done with it.  DeleteDC is *only* for device contexts that you created.

To draw text to this window, you can use functions like [TextOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using that DC (before you release it).

PAINTSTRUCT is for handling WM_PAINT messages (which is the more common way to draw to a Window).  It looks like you're instead trying to draw directly from another thread on a regular basis.  GDI isn't very good at dealing with multiple threads, so you might have some problems with this approach.  But if your BitBlts are working, then a TextOut should work as well.

Comment: The loop in the thread is infinite; the deleteDC will never be called. I'm not sure why it's there (adapted this code). When the program exits, the loop does.

Comment: @Yuri Kahn:  There's a DeleteDC in MakeSurface, near the botton of the code sample, just before it creates the thread.  That should be a ReleaseDC.  The DeleteDC in the thread proc was probably intended to clean up hdcMem rather than hdc, but, you're right that it will never be called.